# I can't connect to server intarfaces after adding external link to server. Configuring routes in CentOS

Tags: networking

What gateway should be set on interface enp0s8(enp0s9) and router R2 to make server (CentOS) share internet connection to vlans hosts [(attachment )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxIdh.png).
How to configure other CentOS insterfaces to route connection from enp0s3.
 I tried to do so [using this site](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-static-routes.html)  but it didn't work.
For now gateway for enp0s8 and enp0s9 are set accordingly:  192.168.3.2 and 192.168.4.2.
I can ping server(enp0s8 and enp0s9)<-->vlans host while link from enp0s3 to eth1 is not present.
 After adding this link I can't ping server interfaces at all(from vlans hosts).

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I set static route in CentOS:

1. Create: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-enp0s8
2. Type in created file:

   ```
   default 192.168.1.101  
   192.168.20.0/24 via 192.168.3.2  
   192.168.10.0/24 via 192.168.3.2
   ```
3. On R2 I set ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.3.1

This configuration works on a reduced set of devices [(attachment)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIiFV.png)

[image]